# Robotium : Is there a way to check for an activity to NOT exist?

Tags: android-activity, robotium, assertions, disaster-recovery

I'm automating an app that shows some overlay messages anywhere on the app for several scenarios, such as app installed for the first time etc. (I'm fairly new to Robotium too.)

The overlay displays a text that goes away by swiping or clicking on it. Also, there are different types of these overlays with different unique text on it. (let's call it Activity A)

I wanted to create a robust test case that handles this case gracefully. From the test's perspective we won't know that the activity A will be present all the time. But I want to recover from the scenario if it does, by writing a method that I can call any time. Currently, the tearDown method gets called since my expected activity name doesn't match.

Also, even if the activity A exists, there are other predefined overlay texts too. So, if I use solo.waitForText("abc") to check for text "abc", I may see the overlay 2 with the text "pqr" instead.

So I was looking for a way to automate this, and I can't use solo.assertCurrentActivity() or solo.waitForActivity methods as they just stop the execution after the first failure.

So any guidance is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the waitFor methods return a boolean. So you can use waitForActivity() exactly as you want to. If the Activity doesn't exist it will return false.

Answer (score 1):

You can check which Activity is current:

```
Activity current = solo.getCurrentActivity();
```